# Git Commands run in a loop on a directory string fail while running individually works

Tags: bash, git, shell, module

I am working on a build script for a website deployment and as part of the process I have to do some cleanup on the code-base so that directories/modules pull in via composer that still have their ".git" directory will actually get committed to the deploy repo.

I am running a scan for these directories and saving the output to a string variable. Then I am looping through each line of the string (each line being a separate directory) and attempting to clear the information from the git cache before adding the directory to the repository.

```
gitSubmodules=$(fin exec sudo find docroot/modules/contrib -type d -name ".git" -print)
submodules=$(echo $gitSubmodules | sed -e 's/\/.git//g')
```

The first command finds the directories. The second one remotes the ".git" subdirectories.

Then I run my loop:

```
while read -r brokenDir; do
  echo "Cleaning directory: ${brokenDir}"
  git rm -r --cached "${brokenDir}"
  echo "Adding directory: ${brokenDir}"
  git add -f "${brokenDir}"
done <<< "$submodules"
```

**The string within `$submodules` is as follows:**

> docroot/modules/contrib/flag docroot/modules/contrib/google_tag
>   docroot/modules/contrib/image_raw_formatter
>   docroot/modules/contrib/jsonapi_extras
>   docroot/modules/contrib/views_contextual_filters_or
>   docroot/modules/contrib/views_tree

**Each being on their own line when echoed to the terminal:**

[image]

**For whatever reason it refuses to recognize the directory doing it this way. I get the following errors:**

> Cleaning directory: docroot/modules/contrib/flag fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/flag?' did not match any files Adding
>   directory: docroot/modules/contrib/flag fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/flag?' did not match any files Cleaning
>   directory: docroot/modules/contrib/google_tag fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/google_tag?' did not match any files Adding
>   directory: docroot/modules/contrib/google_tag fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/google_tag?' did not match any files Cleaning
>   directory: docroot/modules/contrib/image_raw_formatter fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/image_raw_formatter?' did not match any files
>   Adding directory: docroot/modules/contrib/image_raw_formatter fatal:
>   pathspec 'docroot/modules/contrib/image_raw_formatter?' did not match
>   any files Cleaning directory: docroot/modules/contrib/jsonapi_extras
>   fatal: pathspec 'docroot/modules/contrib/jsonapi_extras?' did not
>   match any files Adding directory:
>   docroot/modules/contrib/jsonapi_extras fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/jsonapi_extras?' did not match any files
>   Cleaning directory:
>   docroot/modules/contrib/views_contextual_filters_or fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/views_contextual_filters_or?' did not match
>   any files Adding directory:
>   docroot/modules/contrib/views_contextual_filters_or fatal: pathspec
>   'docroot/modules/contrib/views_contextual_filters_or?' did not match
>   any files Cleaning directory: docroot/modules/contrib/views_tree
>   fatal: pathspec 'docroot/modules/contrib/views_tree?' did not match
>   any files Adding directory: docroot/modules/contrib/views_tree fatal:
>   pathspec 'docroot/modules/contrib/views_tree?' did not match any files

I tried writing the variable like this too `$brokenDir` and that doesn't fix it. My bash scripting skills are weak, I know.

When I run the command manually on the directories it works just fine. I believe the problem is with my use of the variable. But I don't understand how I am using it wrong.

What should I be doing differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured this out. I just had to trim the whitespace around the `$brokenDir` variable that it doesn't visually render. Also had to skip empty values.

My loop changed into this.

```
while read -r brokenDir; do
  if [ ! -z "$brokenDir" ]
  then
    # Trim the whitespace
    CLEANED_DIR="$(echo -e "${brokenDir}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

    echo "Cleaning directory $CLEANED_DIR"
    git rm -r --cached $CLEANED_DIR

    echo "Adding directory $CLEANED_DIR"
    git add -f $CLEANED_DIR
  fi
done <<< "$submodules"
```

I guess I could also trim it before trying to check to see if it is empty as well. This worked for me though.